# Flash/AS3 TLFTextField scrollbar

Tags: actionscript-3, tlf

I cannot display the scrollbar in a TLFTextFiled.

I tried with both ways:

```
1. TLFT.controller.verticalScrollPolicy='ON'
   TLFT.textFlow.flowComposer.updateAllControllers();

2. var scrollBar:UIScrollBar=new UIScrollBar();
   scrollBar.scrollTarget =TLFT;
```

The first one doesn't work and doesn't show any error.
The second one gives compile error because scrollTarget can be TextField only (that's strange because in the [documentation](http://help.adobe.com/it_IT/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/controls/UIScrollBar.html#scrollTarget) scrollTarget is DisplayObject)

Thank you! F.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved:

the UIScrollBar in the library came from a CS4 Flash file, replacing it with Windows/Components/UIScrollBar all works fine.